# Tkinter freezes with multiple threads

Tags: python, multithreading, user-interface, tkinter, opencv

I have developed a **producer-consumer program** in Python, with one producer (which is reading frames from a camera at high speed) and two consumers (one for displaying the video in a **cv2 window**, and the other for saving each frame in the disk). The three Threads are connected by 2 queues (q1 and q2), one for each consumer, since nothing should block image acquisition and display. I have tried this part independently and it works fine. Here I have adapted the class code so the acquisition is now "faked" by putting frames full of zeros in the queues.

```
import multiprocessing 
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import filedialog
import PIL.Image, PIL.ImageTk
import cv2
from threading import Thread,Lock,Semaphore
import queue
import time
from tifffile import imsave
import numpy as np 
import os

class VideoGet():  
    
        def __init__(self,folder,record):

            self.record = record
            self.counter=0
            self.folder = folder
            
        def displayer(self,q2):
            while q2.empty() is False:
                    framedisplay = q2.get()
                    cv2.imshow("Video", framedisplay)
                    cv2.waitKey(1)
                    q2.task_done()
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            
        def consumer(self,q):
         
             while q.empty() is False:
                frame_get = q.get()
                imsave(os.path.join(self.folder,(str(self.counter)+'.tiff')), frame_get)
                self.counter=self.counter+1
                q.task_done()
        
        def producer(self,buffer,q,q2):

            while self.record is True:
               frame=np.zeros_like(buffer)
               q.put(frame)
               q2.put(frame)
               del frame

        def run(self,buffer,q,q2):
            
                prod_thread=Thread(target=self.producer,args=(buffer,q,q2,))
                display_thread=Thread(target=self.displayer,args=(q2,))
                con_thread= Thread(target=self.consumer, args=(q,))
                
                prod_thread.start()
                display_thread.start()
                con_thread.start()
                
                prod_thread.join()
                display_thread.join()
                con_thread.join()
```

I want to create a small tkinter GUI just with three buttons, one asking for a folder, another for starting the acquisition ( that will pop up the cv2 window), and the last one for stoping and killing the full system. I developed a class that calls the threads when the buttons are correctly clicked. **The cv2 windows appear and the frames are saved, but the GUI freezes and is not responding anymore, so I can not click stop anymore**. I guess the problems are the threads are not working as I would expect.

**Any idea how to locate or call the threads correctly?.
And maybe how to display the frames in the GUI instead and not in a cv2 window?**

PS: I know is a bit long code but I did not know how to condense it better

```
class VideoGUI():
    
    def __init__(self, window, window_title):

        self.window = window
        self.window.title(window_title)

        bottom_frame = Frame(self.window)
        
        bottom_frame.pack(side=BOTTOM, pady=5)

        self.record = True   # Parameter that controls pause button
        self.btn_select=Button(bottom_frame, text="Select a folder", width=15, command=self.open_file)
        self.btn_select.grid(row=0, column=0)

        # Play Button
        self.btn_play=Button(bottom_frame, text="Play", width=15, command=self.play_video)
        self.btn_play.grid(row=0, column=1)

        # Pause Button
        self.btn_pause=Button(bottom_frame, text="Stop", width=15, command=self.pause_video)
        self.btn_pause.grid(row=0, column=2)
        self.buffer=np.zeros(shape=(513,640), dtype=np.uint16)
        self.disp_queue=queue.Queue()
        self.save_queue=queue.Queue()
        self.window.mainloop()

    def open_file(self):

        self.folder=filedialog.askdirectory(title="Select folder")
        self.video_object=VideoGet(self.folder,self.record)

    def play_video(self):
 
        try:
             self.video_object.run(self.buffer,self.save_queue,self.disp_queue)
        except:
            print('no play')

    def pause_video(self):
        
        try:    
            self.video_object.record=False
        except:
            self.window.destroy()
    
# Create a window and pass it to videoGUI Class
if __name__=='__main__':
    
    video_object=VideoGUI(Tk(),"camera")
```

Comment: When multithreading, all usage of tkinter must occur in only one thread and that no lengthly processing that interferes with its `mainloop()` can occur or it will hang — like what happens in the `VideoGet.run()` method with its thread `join()` calls. The usual workaround is to use queues to pass data between threads and have the tkinter GUI **poll** them periodically using the universal widget [`after()`](https://web.archive.org/web/20190222214221id_/http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/universal.html) method. There are numerous examples of doing that in answers on this site.

Comment: Calling `join()` will block the application until the thread finishes.

Comment: yes indeed! this was the problem, I was misunderstanding the goal of joining on the threads. At least that part seems to be solved